# Is there a way to test my website in iOS Instagram in-app browser?

Tags: reactjs, inappbrowser, mobile-browser

My react app has a page that has input fields and buttons on it. The website works on mobile browsers, however on iOS in the Instagram in-app browser, whenever a user clicks on an input field and the keyboard shows the user is unable to click back into the text field or the button on the page.

What's the best way to be able to test and debug my website in the iOS instagram in-app browser?

Comment: did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: Negative @MartenZander - I had to do a workaround - basically made a dummy instagram account, duplicated my site on a testing domain and added the url to the dummy instagram account

Comment: yep, that's the trick. I was working the same way yesterday.

Comment: @pjmanning Can you please explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I use [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) (paid platform) for testing. In this case you can open IOS device with safari browser, then push "Show Home Screen" aside settings button, then look for App Store on the home page and download Instagram browser.

Answer (score 0):

Run your development server and your PC and make sure your pc is connected to the same network as the phone.

Then direct message someone your local ip address where the sites development server is running. I'm able to access my development site directly doing so. Fast refresh also works. However I haven't figured out how to see console logs yet.